# Unable to read from serial in c#, but works in python

Tags: python, c#

I am unable to read from serial port in C#, all of the settings are matching (baud, sbit etc...), the code actually sends the SCPI code to my gadget, but it is not responding (the gadget).

I have a very similar code in Python 3.7 and that is working correctly, with the same gadget and with every other.

So this is the C# code:

```
SerialPort com = new SerialPort("COM22",9600,Parity.Even,7,StopBits.Two);
        com.Open();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        com.DiscardOutBuffer();
        com.DiscardInBuffer();

        Console.Write("SCPI: ");
        string cmd = Console.ReadLine();
        com.Write(cmd + "\n");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        string answ = com.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("The answer "+answ);
        com.Close();
```

Here in C# I have also tried `ReadChar()`, `ReadByte()` and `ReadLine()`...

And also I have tried to change `HandShake`.

And here goes the Python code:

```
import time
import serial

while 1:
    try:
        comPort = input("Insert COM port num to use: ")

        ser = serial.Serial(
            port='COM' + comPort,
            baudrate=9600,
            parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
            bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
        )  # serial port settings
        ser.isOpen()
        break
    except Exception:
        print("Bad COM port. Try again.")

print('Enter your commands below.\nInsert "exit" to leave the application.')

while 1:
    cmd = input("Insert your command: ")  # insert the commands
    if cmd == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\n'))  # send the character to the device
        out = " "
        time.sleep(2)  # wait one second before reading output (give device time to answer)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1).decode("ascii")

        print(">>" + out)  # output the answer
```

As you can see they are very similar, with the same waiting time...

Comment: The Python code doesn't prove much - there are no problems with serial ports in .NET (people would have noticed 10-15 years ago). There's no reason to add any kind of delay either, as far as the port is concerned. Are you sure you're connecting to the *correct* port for starters? You don't configure handshaking in either snippet.

Comment: Yes I am sure, I've checked it multiple times and tried other settings but did not work. So I've decided to go back to the default settings. And for the handshake: I've tried _XOnXOff_ , but didn't stick with it, because the code didn't work either.

Comment: And also I know there is no problem with the serial port in .NET, because I have an other code, which is working perfectly, with other gadgets. With this gadget, I can only work in Python, because somehow in C# I can't get it working.

Comment: In the C# code you read and write *strings* while the Python code reads/writes individual bytes. Have you checked how many bytes are in the port's buffers, eg with [BytesToRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) ? Try handling the port's events, at least [ErrorReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.errorreceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: The default handshake is none, which means your code *has* to check the RTS/CTS attributes, both in Python and C#. This means your Python code works by chance only - adding delays isn't going to solve that issue. Again, what is the gadget? How is its handshaking configured? You may be trying to send before the device is ready to receive. The best option is to use RtsCts handshaking

Comment: Handshaking and configuration are described in your device's manual/fact sheet. So what device are you using?

Comment: It is an HP 34401 MultiMeter.

Comment: A [16-year old multimeter ?](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/handshake-problem-when-trying-to-work-with-Agilent-34401A/td-p/119939?profile.language=en)?  If you find and [check the manual](https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/41045/agilent-technologies-34401a.html?page=157) it uses RTS\CTS. If you *don't* use RTS\CTS you need to select a lower baud rate, *and* change the wiring

Comment: I figured out I had to add these two lines: _com.RtsEnable = true; _com.DtrEnable = true;_
Thanks for the help.

Comment: According to the multimeter's manual this *disables* handshaking. Which also means you need to lower the connection speed.  Why don't you use the multimeter's default, RtsCts ?